# Finding solutions for the Riccati equation $y'+y+y^2 = 2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find two solutions in $\mathbb{R}$ for the Riccati equation $$y'+y+y^2 = 2$$
>   Which satisfy the following initial conditions:
>
> a) $y = b$ when $x=0$, $-2 \leq b < 1$
>
> b) $y = b$ when $x=0$, $b \geq 1$ or $b < -2$

**What I tried to do:**
First I supposed the equation could admit constant solutions, such that it would reduce to the quadratic equation:$$y^2 +y -2 =0$$
 Which admits $y_{1} = 1$ and $y_{2} = -2$ as solutions
Then, $y = y_{i} + \frac{1}{v_{i}}$ ($i = 1$ or $i=2$) is also a solution if $v_{i}$ satisfies: $$v_{i}' + v_{i}(1+2y_{i}) = -1$$
(Note: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) you can find an explanation for this last equation)

Finally, I tried $y_{1}=1$  and I got:$$v_{1}' + 3 v_{1} = -1$$
The solution would be: $$v_{1} = a_{1}e^{-3x} + \frac{e^{-3x}}{3} - \frac{1}{3}$$
Where $a_{1}$ specifies the initial condition for $v_{1}$. 
**I don't know how to use this to get a solution for the original Ricatti equation satisfying a initial condition for $y$ given in the exercise.**
If I substitute $v_{1}$, I would get $$y(x) = 1 + \frac{3}{e^{-3x}(3a_{1}+1) -1}$$
and, as $y(0) = b$, $$ b = \frac{a_{1}+1}{a_{1}} $$
But then $b$ is not in just one of the intervals given... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ODE is separable. It can be written as:
$$\frac{y'}{2-y-y^2}=1\tag{1} $$
and by integrating both sides of $(1)$ we get:
$$\log\left(\frac{2+y}{1-y}\right)=3t+C \tag{2}$$
hence:
$$ y(t) = \frac{K e^{3t}-2}{K e^{3t}+1}\tag{3} $$
where the value of $K$ depends on the initial conditions.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand how you got from (1) to (2)... could you indicate what method did you use?

Comment: I found the separation you did a nice approach. Thank you

Comment: @El Cid: I simply integrated both terms exploiting $$\int\frac{dx}{2-x-x^2}=\frac{1}{3}\int\left(\frac{1}{2+x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\,dx = \frac{1}{3}\log\left(\frac{2+x}{1-x}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

You did nothing wrong up to your last conclusion. $b=\frac{a+1}{a}$ is equivalent to $a=\frac{1}{b-1}$ and
$$
y(x)=1+\frac{3(b-1)}{e^{-3x}(2+b)-(b-1)}=\frac{e^{-3x}(2+b)+2(b-1)}{e^{-3x}(2+b)-(b-1)}
$$
so that for $b=1$ and $b=-2$ everything cancels to a constant solution.

---

The only property that distinguishes both cases is that for $-2\le b\le 1$ there is no pole, i.e., the solution is defined on the whole of $\Bbb R$. While in the other case there is a pole and one has to select the branch corresponding to the initial condition.